# How to get Implicit parameter into scope when using currying

Tags: scala

Is there a way to pass an implicit parameter into a curried function. I am using a dirty fix  (se below) but it is not pretty. I would love to be able to pass the implicit var "i" as a implicit param.

```
case class myLoaner() {
  implicit val i = "How to get this val into scope within the session function"

  def withCode[T](session: => T): Either[Exception, T] = {
    try {
      Right(session)
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => {
        Left(ex)
      }
    }
  }
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val r = myLoaner()

    r.withCode {
      implicit val imp = r.i // I want to get rid of this line of code and use the implict val defined above directly
      val h = new Helper
      h.run 
    }
  }

  class Helper {
    def run(implicit i: String) {
      println(i)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After `val r = myLoaner()`, you can write

```
import r.i
```

or

```
import r._
```

to do what you want. Alternatively, you can mark `r` itself `implicit` and provide this extra definition:

```
implicit def loanerString(implicit loaner: myLoaner): String = loaner.i
```

... but now a little bit too many implicits start floating around for my taste, so use that wisely. Sometimes too much implicit magic harms the readability and understandability of your code.

Comment: Aye, adding import r._ to the beginning of the execution block is pretty much your only viable option. My personal style preference is to place it after the curly brace but on the same line, so it doesn't appear to be an integral part of the execution block.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass implicit parameters directly, e.g. as `h.run(r.i)`.